# Sum by year in a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I wrote following  query

```
Select 
   SUM(CASE WHEN tr.flg = 'SEND' THEN TR.PR_TRN_AMT ELSE 0 END) AS PR_CURYEAR,
   SUM(CASE WHEN tr.flg ='RECIVED' THEN TR.PR_TRN_AMT ELSE 0   END) AS PR_CURYEAR    
FROM 
   [TRNDB].[dbo].[DAILY_PR] AS TR,
   [TRNDB].[dbo].[PR_MAIN] AS M,
WHERE
   M.PR_ID=TR.PR_CODE  
   AND TR.TRAN_DATE BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'
```

This query result shows correct details. But I want sum of from 2017-01-01 to 2017-12-31 and 2016-01-01 to 2016-12-31 in same query result. How should I change my query?

Comment: please use ansi style for joining, this type of joining is not used anymore in decades...

Comment: the format of your date can be wrongly understood. If you really want to build your query in code like this, than use a language neutral date format  like 'yyyyMMdd' and prepare for sql injection hacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN (TR.TRAN_DATE BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31') AND tr.flg = 'SEND' THEN TR.PR_TRN_AMT ELSE 0 END) AS PR_CURYEAR,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (TR.TRAN_DATE BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31') AND tr.flg ='RECIVED' THEN TR.PR_TRN_AMT ELSE 0   END) AS PR_CURYEAR,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (TR.TRAN_DATE BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31') AND tr.flg = 'SEND' THEN TR.PR_TRN_AMT ELSE 0 END) AS PR_PREYEAR,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (TR.TRAN_DATE BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31') AND tr.flg ='RECIVED' THEN TR.PR_TRN_AMT ELSE 0   END) AS PR_PREYEAR
FROM 
    [TRNDB].[dbo].[DAILY_PR] AS TR 
    INNER JOIN [TRNDB].[dbo].[PR_MAIN] AS M ON M.PR_ID=TR.PR_CODE 
WHERE 
    TR.TRAN_DATE BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your where clause...

```
where  
   M.PR_ID=TR.PR_CODE 
   AND TR.TRAN_DATE BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'
```

You may wish to put the year in the query as well. I added it and used explicit joins:

```
Select 
    SUM(CASE WHEN tr.flg = 'SEND' THEN TR.PR_TRN_AMT ELSE 0 END) AS PR_CURYEAR,
    SUM(CASE WHEN tr.flg ='RECIVED' THEN TR.PR_TRN_AMT ELSE 0   END) AS PR_CURYEAR,
    DATEPART(year,TR.TRAN_DATE) as TheYear
FROM 
    [TRNDB].[dbo].[DAILY_PR] AS TR 
    INNER JOIN [TRNDB].[dbo].[PR_MAIN] AS M ON
    M.PR_ID=TR.PR_CODE
WHERE  
    TR.TRAN_DATE BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'
GROUP BY
    DATEPART(year,TR.TRAN_DATE)
```

Or perhaps like so, which splits it into seperate columns.

```
Select 
    SUM(CASE WHEN tr.flg = 'SEND' AND DATEPART(year,TR.TRAN_DATE) = 2017 THEN TR.PR_TRN_AMT ELSE 0 END) AS PR_CURYEAR,
    SUM(CASE WHEN tr.flg ='RECIVED' AND DATEPART(year,TR.TRAN_DATE) = 2017  THEN TR.PR_TRN_AMT ELSE 0   END) AS PR_CURYEAR,
    SUM(CASE WHEN tr.flg = 'SEND' AND DATEPART(year,TR.TRAN_DATE) = 2016 THEN TR.PR_TRN_AMT ELSE 0 END) AS PR_PREVYEAR,
    SUM(CASE WHEN tr.flg ='RECIVED' AND DATEPART(year,TR.TRAN_DATE) = 2016  THEN TR.PR_TRN_AMT ELSE 0   END) AS PR_PREVYEAR
FROM 
    [TRNDB].[dbo].[DAILY_PR] AS TR 
    INNER JOIN [TRNDB].[dbo].[PR_MAIN] AS M ON
    M.PR_ID=TR.PR_CODE
WHERE  
    TR.TRAN_DATE BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to group your results by year.

```
Select datepart(year,TR.TRAN_DATE ) [year],
    SUM(CASE WHEN tr.flg = 'SEND' THEN TR.PR_TRN_AMT ELSE 0 END) AS PR_CURYEAR,
    SUM(CASE WHEN tr.flg ='RECIVED' THEN TR.PR_TRN_AMT ELSE 0   END) AS PR_CURYEAR
FROM [TRNDB].[dbo].[DAILY_PR] AS TR 
join [TRNDB].[dbo].[PR_MAIN] AS M on  M.PR_ID=TR.PR_CODE
where datepart(year,TR.TRAN_DATE ) in (2016,2017)
group by datepart(year,TR.TRAN_DATE )
```